# using multiple routers in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-forms

```
 <app-menu></app-menu>
 <app-menu2></app-menu2>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Need some logic, I have two routers called `<app-menu>` and `<app-menu2>`.

I am developing an application which is having login. After login, I want to see only `<app-menu2>`.

Now displays both of the menus. I want to display `<app-menu>` before login and `<app-menu2>` after login.give me some logics.

I tried to hide the appmenus. That does not works. Please give me suggestion as soon as possible.

Comment: Do you have a service to handle the authentication ?

Comment: yes runit and my code...................                   this.myservice.getData(this.url).subscribe((resdata) => this.logindata = resdata);for(let i=0;i<this.logindata.length;i++){

 if(this.logindata[i].username==this.user.username && this.logindata[i].password==this.user.password)
  {
     
       this.router.navigateByUrl("/courses");
       console.log("success");

       return true;
 }

Comment: Please edit your question and include your service implementation. It is hard to read code in the comments

Answer (score 2):

You should use 2 different pages/templates, one for authed and one for not authed.

See: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

like

```
    { 
        path: 'Login', 
        component: LoginComponent,
    }
    {
        path: 'Authed',
        component: YourLoggedInComponent
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ChildComponent,


            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: hi jones, i didn't understand that docs. if you know any alternative documents suggest me. thanks

Comment: You shouldn't render a component even with *ngIf, you should have to separate pages/templates, one for the login page and one for the logged in state, once you have authenticated you re-route the user to that template wich have the menu2 component.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at how authentication work, and try to create a service to handle that properly. When your service is done, you should have a method `.logged()` exposed by the service and then you can use it in your component.

Actually your service is very unsafe, you are actually loading all users and check password within the client, anyone with a little knowledge should be able to bypass the login.

I suggest you to look at:
https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-authentication/
and at:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial